# Trying to run the multiple powershell scripts from wix installer

Tags: windows, installation, wix3.5, wix3.7, wix3.6

Here I have tried something but it dose not work at all can anyone guide me how to run the multiple scripts from installer

```
<SetProperty Id="PS1"
         Before="PS1"
         Sequence="execute"
             Value ="&quot;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe&quot;-NoLogo -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -InputFormat None -NoProfile -File &quot;-Command &quot;cd '[INSTALLLOCATION]'; &amp; '[#ps1]' ; exit $$($Error.Count)&quot;" />


<CustomAction Id="PS1" 
              BinaryKey="WixCA" 
              DllEntry="WixQuietExec" 
              Execute="deferred" 
              Return="check" 
              Impersonate="no" />
        
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="PS1" After='InstallFiles'>
        <![CDATA[NOT Installed]]>
    </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

to destination folder files get copied but it said like this why I dont know ,Inside a log file it shows like this

```
WixQuietExec:  Processing -File '-Command cd' failed because the file does not have a '.ps1' extension. Specify a valid Windows PowerShell script file name, and then try again.
WixQuietExec:  Windows PowerShell
WixQuietExec:  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
WixQuietExec:  
WixQuietExec:  Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6
WixQuietExec:  
WixQuietExec:  Error 0xfffd0000: Command line returned an error.
WixQuietExec:  Error 0xfffd0000: QuietExec Failed
WixQuietExec:  Error 0xfffd0000: Failed in ExecCommon method
CustomAction PS1 returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't always happen, but the error message is pretty clear. Here it is word-wrapped, so it is easier to read:

```
WixQuietExec:  Processing -File '-Command cd' failed because 
               the file does not have a '.ps1' extension. 
               Specify a valid Windows PowerShell script file
               name, and then try again.
```

That's a PowerShell error message.

Comment: I want to run three powershell scripts sequentially but does not run only one script 
 run successfully and this script is here                                                                                                          dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestartLinux /all /norestart
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart

Comment: will you guide me how to run powershell scripts through installer cause I am unable to do that I need to run three scripts sequentially